# error bar shows up on page load

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a page with the error bar displaying on the page load. Below I have the div that the error message is in.

```
  @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
                    <div id="validationMessages" class="validation-summary-errors"></div>
```

And this is the css that it uses

```
.validation-summary-errors {position: fixed; bottom: 45px; width: 100%; background: rgba(255,197,197,0.9); z-index: 1000; padding: 10px; text-align: center; left: 0; border-top: 1px solid #900;}
```

does anyone know how to make it not show on page load?

Thanks

Comment: When it is your page then you should know the reason why it pops up. Sure you can hide it, but it looks like there are deeper problems

Comment: it pops up when there is even no error..

Comment: Have you checked that all validation rules are implemented and executed properly?

Answer (score 0):

From a CSS perspective, you could just hide that message by adding `display:none;` to the existing rule.  (JavaScript could make the message appear again.)  But you should really look into resolving the root cause of the validation error.